# Why __get__ method of a descriptor in Python is called inside of hassattr()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-descriptors

Suppose

```
class D:
    def __init__(self,id): self.id = id

    def __get__(self,obj,type=None):
        print(self.id,"__get__ is called")

class C:
    d1 = D(1)
    d2 = D(2) 
    d3 = D(3)

c = C()
```

then during the call `hasattr(c,"d1")` the `__get__` method of `C.d1` is called. Why? Shouldn't `hasattr()` just check the dictionaries?

The same (but weirder) happens when `<tab>` is presses for completion in an interactive CPython-version-3.6.10-session, as in `c.d<tab>`. In this case `__get__` will be called for all matching attributes except the last one.
What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the `help` for `hasattr` (or the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr):

```
Help on built-in function hasattr in module builtins:

hasattr(obj, name, /)
    Return whether the object has an attribute with the given name.

    This is done by calling getattr(obj, name) and catching AttributeError.
```

So no, it doesn't just "check dictionaries", it couldn't do that because not all objects have dictionaries as namespaces to begin with, e.g. built-in objects, or user-defined objects with `__slots__`.

`getattr(obj, name)` will correctly invoke the equivalent machinery as:

```
obj.name
```

Which would call the descriptor's `__get__`

Comment: I see. It means, in particular, that `hasattr` in case of positive outcome is as expensive as the corresponding `__get__`.  Is there a good reason behind this?

Comment: Where does tab-completion mechanism gets the list of attributes to match against?

Comment: @R.Matveev: The presence of a descriptor doesn't mean an object actually has the corresponding attribute. It's the descriptor's job to determine whether the object has the attribute, and the descriptor can say no.

Comment: For example, if you write a class with `__slots__ = ('a',)`, the class will have a slot descriptor for `a`, but the descriptor will raise an AttributeError if you try to access the `a` attribute on an instance where you didn't actually set a value for `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the tab completion, but `hasattr` does call `__get__`. It is [documented as well](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr):

> The arguments are an object and a string. The result is `True` if the
> string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, `False` if not.
> (This is implemented by calling `getattr(object, name)` and seeing
> whether it raises an `AttributeError` or not.)